# Prove a corollary of Poincaré-Bendixson Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

> Consider the 2-D system $\dot{x}=F(x)$ and let $S\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be compact s.t.
>
> - (1) $S$ contains no equilibria, or, contains exactly one equilibrium point $x_e$ s.t. all the eigenvalues of $D F(x_e)$ have positive real parts;
> - (2) $S$ is positively invariant.
>
> Then $S$ contains a closed orbit.

I believe above tells us how to use Poincaré-Bendixson Theorem, but I have some difficulty in proving it. If $S$ contains no equilibria, its easy to see the corresponding $\omega$ limit set satisfies the Theorem' s condition. If $S$ contains a unstable one equilibrium point as it says, the flow can not stop at the point, the proposition seems natural but I do not know how to write a valid proof. Also what happens when we have two equilibrium points?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Could you summarize what your version of Poincaré-Bendixson says? I would think of it being identical to the version without equilibrium points, or is it formulated for an annular region?

Comment: Each nonempty bounded $\omega$ limit set of a $C^1$ planar flow, which does not contain an equilibrium point, is a closed orbit. (--from the book of Smale)

Comment: Hmm if all eigenvalues are positive, the solutions move away from $x_e$. You might just cut out a little ball $S \cap B_\varepsilon(x_e)$ out of $S$ to get a positive invariant compact set without equilibrium point...

Comment: If the orbit is close enough to $x_e$... I do not see how to write rigorously.

Comment: Take a Lyapunov function, constructed with the Jacobian and its eigen-decomposition, and cut out the interior of a small level set. Or in other words, adapt the ball to be an elliptical set, or make it the ball in some adapted norm.